# gdb in one command

Tags: gdb

When I debug an executable `program` with arguments `arg1 arg2` with `gdb` I perform the following sequence

```
gdb
file ./program
run arg1 arg2
bt
quit
```

How can I do the same from one command line in shell script?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass commands to gdb on the command line with option `-ex`. You need to repeat this for each command. This can be useful when your program needs to read stdin so you don't want to redirect it.  Eg, for `od -c`

```
echo abc |
gdb -ex 'break main' -ex 'run -c' -ex bt -ex cont -ex quit  od
```

So in particular for your question, you can use:

```
gdb -ex 'run arg1 arg2' -ex bt -ex quit ./program
```

Comment: Why `echo abc` , what is `break main`, what is `-c`, what is `od`, which is the tested executable?

Comment: The example is just to show how `-ex` can be useful. I've added the answer to your problem to the end of the post.

Comment: How can I get rid of `A debugging session is active.

 Inferior 1 [process 13597] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n)` in your example?

Comment: Simply replace the `-ex quit` by `-batch` to avoid any interaction.

Comment: Why do you use apostrophes in `'run arg1 arg2'` and don't in `-ex bt`?

Comment: The `-ex` option wants a single string value, so when you want to pass it a string with a space in it you need to use single or double quotes to stop the shell from splitting the string into 2 strings. You can use `-ex 'bt'` if you like for consistency, but the shell removes all these quotes before they get to gdb as parameters.

Comment: `-ex quit` will not be necessary if you use `-batch` option.

Answer (score 6):

The commands could be fed in on standard input:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gdb -q <<EOF
file ./program
run arg1 arg2
bt
quit
EOF
```

Or the commands can be placed in `afile` and `gdb` run with `gdb -batch -x afile`, or if you hate newlines (and the maintenance coder) with a fancy shell you can do it all on a single line (a different way to express the heredoc version):

```
gdb -q <<< "file ./program"$'\n'run$'\n'...
```

Comment: why not give `afile` an `.sh` extension once it is a shell script?

Comment: Using exec will prevent executing after gdb exit.

Comment: @Viesturs I never put `*.sh` on my shell scripts

Answer (score 2):

To pass arguments to your program on the GDB command line, use `gdb --args`.

```
gdb --args ./program arg1 arg2
bt
```