# Get backtrace from core dump using gdb via shell script(non interactive)

Tags: linux, core-dump, gdb

I have core dump file and gdb. 
I can do

```
 gdb <executable> <core_file>
 (gdb)bt
```

This will give me backtrace but I want to do this using a shell script and in non-interactive mode. Writing `gdb exe core` takes me to gdb CLI and needs manual intervention.
Any idea how can I automate it?

Comment: Related: [gdb in one command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456294/gdb-in-one-command)

Answer (score 3):

got it by --help

just write all the commands in a file, lets say file.txt. Pass this file in --command.

```
gdb --command=file.txt exe core_file
```

The content of file.txt

```
bt
quit
```